# Is there a reason why Jack turned away when they dropped Glen's body?

Tags: 13-hours

I know it's been a year or so since the release of *13 Hours*, but watching it again made me think about this scene. Is there a reason/significance to Jack Silva turning away when Glen's body was dropped? I know it's horribly disrespectful to do something like that, but I was just wondering if there was a special significance.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's Glen whose body is being dropped? Isn't it Rone? If I remember correctly Glen is the who came in support with the Delta operators and a few others. It being Rone also explains why Jack would react like this. They were very close.

Comment: Well it could be him too... Not sure about that. But if I remember correctly, Jack and Glen were close too. They were SEALS together as well.

Comment: You're right about Glen and Jack. Glen does die. I'm pretty sure that's Rone's body being dropped though. I don't think they address who it is, but I assume it's Rone. We barely see Glen, it makes more sense for it be Rone as he had more character development. Either way, the reason seems to be that Jack was close to the person being dropped and that's why he looks away.

Comment: Hmm, now that you mention it, it seems like it. Thanks for clearing my doubts.